# Kernel build "nothing to be done"

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile the kernel version 2.6.20-15 on my Linux 10.10 with 2.6.35-22 kernel. Additionally, this is my assignment.

After I download kernel, extract it and create a new .config file for the new kernel I am trying to command;

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
```

Here is the problem, after the second command I get an error an it says "nothing to be done" but I expect to have some .deb files for the new kernel. In addition this I have added a new system call to the kernel 2.6.20-15. Does anybody have had the problem is the same with me?

Comment: There is no such thing like `Linux 10.10`, you most likely mean Ubuntu, but why is this tagged Debian then?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean Ubuntu 10.10 with Linux 10.10. Probably the kernel you try to compile is just too old (2.6.20 is 2007??). I know for example that Debian 6, that works with kernel 2.6.32 won't work with kernel versions older than 2.6.28!

Comment: There is no `Linux 10.10`, the current 'Linux' (read: Kernel) version is 2.6.38.